# Restore a lost remote file from Coda 2?

Tags: file, caching, server, coda

I was working on JS file on my clients server on Coda 2. The client's server miraculously auto updated itself and the file no longer exists on the remote server. Is it possible that Coda 2 has cached the file locally somewhere? I would lose about 2 weeks work if I don't retrieve the lost file. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

The cache file for me was found as follows on OSX:

1. From the Finder menu select Go > Home
2. From the Finder menu again select Go > Go to folder...
3. Type "Library" and click Go
4. Open the Caches folder
5. Open the Coda 2 folder
6. Do a search in this folder for the file name you're looking for.